# Apps script : new Date(...) of string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

with apps script and google calendar I get the [events with same name](https://gist.github.com/4680055):

```
function authorize() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("calendar");
  var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  
}

function beginEnd(calId, eventName){
  authorize();
  var key = "...";
  var query = encodeURIComponent(eventName); 
  calId = encodeURIComponent(calId);
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    oAuthServiceName: "calendar",
    oAuthUseToken: "always",
  };
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"+
    calId+"/events?q=" + query + "&key=" + key;
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var response = Utilities.jsonParse(request.getContentText());
  var items = response.items;
  for ( i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++){
    var start = (items[i].start.dateTime);
    var end =  (items[i].end.dateTime);
    Logger.log( [start,end]);
  } 
}
```

but, when I try convert start to new Date:

```
var start = (items[i].start.dateTime);
Logger.log(start);
Logger.log( new Date(start) );
```

I get

```
2013-01-21T15:00:00-03:00
Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969
```

why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that date definition doesn't like hyphens...

it works like this, even if I'm sure a better solution can be found (I'm not a regex expert ;-)

```
Logger.log(new Date('2013-01-21T15:00:00-03:00'.replace(/-/g,'/').replace(/[A-Z]/,' ').substr(0,19)))
```

Comment: many thanks, the strange is this : I used this format : `2013-01-21T15:00:00-03:00` in google chrome javascript console and converted to new Date.

Comment: I have run into this problem before, and I believe that it is due to the fact that Google Apps Scripts is using JS 1.8 ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script) )and the date constructor supporting the input you require is only supported in 1.8.5 [more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Description)