# How to fix this date type validation error?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

I have this function:

```
function replaceKeys(documentClass, headersArr, personDataArr){
 for(var i = 0; i<headersArr.length; i++){
  var key = ":" + headersArr[i] + ":";
  var newString = personDataArr[i];
   Logger.log("newString ="+newString);
   Logger.log("(newString instanceof Date) ="+(newString instanceof Date));   
   Logger.log("typeof  newString ="+ ( typeof newString));
   if(newString instanceof Date) {
       newString = newString.getDate() + '/' + (newString.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + newString.getFullYear();
     Logger.log("newString after if = "+newString);
      }     
  replaceString(documentClass, key, newString);
   Logger.log(" ");
  }
}
```

Which isn't working because dates are stored as strings as shown in this logs:

[image]

The data is stored in a google spreadsheet. Then, stringfied and stored in ScriptProperties (only accepts string) and, after, recovery as an array of strings.

I tried something like this: `if(new Date (newString) instanceof Date)` but then I got an error when the string isn't conversible to date format.

How could I set a condition to try something that, when I pass the condition, I can perform something like this:

[image]

Or other way to fix that?

Comment: Where is the data generated, if local then can't you store the date object rather than converting it to an ISO8601 string? Otherwise you will need to create a Date object from the string, which is not hard.

Comment: The data is stored in a google spreadsheet. Then, stringfied and stored in scriptproperties (only accepts string) and, after, recovery as an array of strings.

Comment: Ok, well you just need to convert the string to a Date object, if that is what you need. Split the string into parts and pass them into the Date constructor, and use Date.UTC as your string is in UTC `Z`

Comment: But a lot of the arrays objects aren't dates (ex: names, etc.)

Comment: But you know which fields are what, don't you?

Comment: Then the date is not your only concern, how will you identify which field is a name or anything else?

Comment: Yes, but I was searching for a solution despite this information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parsing+iso+8601+javascript or with a library like http://momentjs.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618497/apps-script-new-date-of-string/14626097#14626097. This could be a solution to convert to date object... it was exactly the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Sergeinsas . I'm waiting for your book (international ship)

Comment: ;) glad to hear that, I hope you won't be disappointed...it's really a book for beginners and you're not a beginner anymore if I judge on the level of your questions !! thx anyway and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information that you have provided.

Javascript

```
function parseMyDate(dateString) {
    var parts = dateString.slice(0, -1).split(/[T\-:\.]/g);

    parts[1] -= 1;
    return new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined, parts));
}

var dateString = '2014-01-21T13:50:20.123Z';

var myDate = parseMyDate(dateString);

console.log(!isNaN(myDate), myDate instanceof Date);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/LDXLx/)

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers work they overcomplicate things.
Dont convert dates back and forth to strings.
Instead save it as integer (date.getTime()) which can be saved to properties (as string) and its trivial to parse the string back into a number and then simply Date(num) gives you the exact date back.

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution: turn the date object into a string before store it in ScriptProperties:

```
function stringifyDates(array){
   for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
      var newString = array[i];
      if(newString instanceof Date){
        newString = newString.getDate() + '/' + (newString.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + newString.getFullYear();
        array[i] = newString;
     }
  }
  return array
}
```

Comment: You could also have used JSON.stringify to make it a string an then JSON.parse to recover your date object.